# Execute command in .csproj to build dependent project programmatically

Tags: .net, build, dependencies, target, csproj

I have 3 projects in my solution:

1. MainProject (.NET 6)
2. Shared Project (.NET 6)
3. Desktop Project (.NET 6 - Windows)

I know i can't make *'Desktop Project'* as dependency of *'MainProject'*, because they are from different SDK.

**My question is:**

Is possible to create a command in *'MainProject.csproj'* to compile the *'Desktop Project.csproj'* and copy released files to 'MainProject' folder

They share same libs and versions, so they must be in same folder.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution!!

1. You have to put the Dependency project in Built tree.

Right click in your MainProject -> Build Dependencies -> Project Dedendencies and check your Depdendency Project.

After this, open your MainProject.csproj.
Probably you have a target named "PublishRun" or samething like this.

Put the follow code inside this target:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssetsSourceFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)TerminalCaixaPDV\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(AssetsSourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

Rebember to change the folder structure in AssetsSourceFiles.

Thanks.